# How to use Node-Inspector on Visual Studio?

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I have just installed node-inspector on my application using visual studio npm manager. On linux env I can use `--debug` to use it. How should I use it on Visual Studio Environment?

Comment: Have you considered using Node.js tools for Visual Studio instead? https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/

Comment: I am using that, but it doesnt integrate with node-inspector

Comment: AFAIK, they provide their own debugger, so that you can debug directly from within VS, no need to use a 3rd party tool like node-inspector.